# Winsock connect is slow

Tags: c++, boost-asio, winsock, winsock2

I have a program that uses Boost.Asio to connect to a server on localhost. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
TcpClient::TcpClient(uint16_t port_number) : socket_(service_)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(service_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query resolver_query("localhost", std::to_string(port_number));
    auto endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(resolver_query);
    boost::asio::connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator);
}
```

The code functions just fine. On Ubuntu, the `connect` function returns almost immediately. However, on Windows it takes over 2 seconds to complete.

Stepping through the boost code, I found the 2 seconds are spent on the [Winsock `connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) function call.

Am I missing something (either in code, or in the environment) that can speed up this call?

Thank you!

Comment: My usual suspect is [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  Hmm, maybe not a suspect in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @Eljay for the comment. I'm not sure that will help, because the slowdown happens before I've even established a connection. I tried enabling the `no_delay` option from boost.asio, but it seems I can't set that option until the socket has already connected.

Comment: @Eljay AFAIK Nagle doesn't apply to `connect()`, only to `send()`.

Comment: Could be related to IPv6. Check what addresses `resolver.resolve` returns. Also, what is the port and the server?

Comment: Maybe an issue with Delayed Acks (`TCP_QUICKACK`)?

Comment: I think this should probably be asked on SuperUser, or something on that order. A quick test on my machine shows `connect` to `localhost` happening in about 0.8 to 1.2 milliseconds. Based on that, I'm pretty sure this is a problem with configuration, not the code.

Comment: my guess is `localhost` is probably returning a ipv4 and ipv6 address, the ipv6 address is tried first then after an error/timeout the ipv4 is tried.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, you are spot on! I printed the results of the query, and found `::1` was the first result on Windows (whereas Ubuntu only returned 127.0.0.1). One solution could be to serve on ipv6, but I solved it by limiting the query to ipv4. If you convert your comment to an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have IPv6 enabled then `resolver_query("localhost", std::to_string(port_number));` will return an IPv4 and IPv6 address (from experience with the IPv6 listed first). If your server isn't listening on IPv6 then `boost::asio::connect` will try IPv6 first, wait for it to fail and only then try IPv4.

Either get your server to listen on IPv6, use "127.0.0.1" instead of localhost or restrict the resolver to only return IPv4:

```
resolver_query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "localhost", std::to_string(port_number));
```

Comment: Pro tip: add `127.0.0.1 localhost` to the `hosts` file to never worry about this later.